# We can mark a question as a favorite question, but why can't we do the same to an answer?

Tags: feature-request, answers, bookmarks

Sometimes a question may not be very useful but the answer may be. I know that the accepted answer is the most useful one to the OP. But for other users, the most useful answer might be some other answer. Being able to mark that answer as a favorite answer would make it easier to find for future reference.

Comment: Just mark the question as a favorite. It's still easy enough to find the answer. I don't see the point in over-complicating the UI.

Comment: Just... favourite the question.

Comment: If there are more answers in the question which answer was the best for me, how could I know in the future? I should re-read all the answers.

Comment: There usually aren't that many answers where it's a problem to scan them looking for the one you're interested in. And in most cases, the answer that was most helpful to you will be near the top, because it was either most helpful to the asker and therefore accepted, or highly upvoted by the community because of its usefulness.

Comment: @CodyGray If you upvote your favorite answer, you'll see your upvote when you go to that question again.

Comment: Answers are pretty meaningless without a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a way of knowing what the best answer for you was you can favorite the question and then upvote the answer that was most helpful for you, even if it is not the accepted answer.

I see why you want a "favorite answer" option, but you can achieve nearly the same concept by just favoriting the question and upvote the most helpful answer(s) for you. This is the idea behind upvotes, just because one answer helped the OP and was accepted doesn't mean it was the best and that's why others can upvote the other answers to move them to the top for future users.

Comment: What if I want to upvote other answers as well?