# Reconsider adding the ability to bookmark answers

Tags: feature-request, answers, bookmarks

Often, when looking through a certain question, I find an answer that captivates my attention more than the question itself.  I would like to find it again, which I can do by following the answer, but I don't want to follow it because:

- You will receive notifications about activity on that answer whether you like it or not.
- You might confuse it with posts in your Following tab that you wanted to follow to track activity, but not for bookmarking.

When I follow a post, it's because I want to know what is happening on that post.  Following an answer when you just wanted to find it again is not really a desirable solution, because of the reasons I gave above.

This was previously requested and [declined by Jeff Atwood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107790/798831) last decade:

> There are plenty of easy ways to to bookmark an answer in your browser:  Right-click the link item under the question, and select "bookmark this link".

I *strongly* disagree.  By that logic, there is no need to have a question-bookmarking system either, if you can browser-bookmark it.

Also, in [Optimizing for pearls, not sand](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/), it says that answers are more important than questions.  I realize that the reputation system now gives and takes equal reputation from either post, but I still consider answers more important than questions.

It would be really nice if we could bookmark answers in addition to questions.  I don't want to bookmark the question and then sift through the answers to find the one I'm interested in.  This would be far more efficient, and wouldn't send you the unnecessary messages a Follow would.

From [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147592/798831):

> It should be noted that the purpose of visitors to the SE sites is to seek answers, not questions. The question asked is merely an impetus to a quality answer.

This is true, so answers are of still greater importance.  I do know that there are similar posts about this, but they were asked over eleven years ago and all have very good points as to why this should be implemented.

Comment: I would up vote this Feature Request for sure :) ...If I had any votes left. :(

Comment: Directing this at Jeff is kind of pointless, as he is no longer actively working at SE.

Comment: Yeah. 32 minutes to go...

Comment: I really agree with you, that answers are more important than questions

Comment: Because it's easy to ask a question but 10,000 times harder to answer one, especially if it's in SE Meta.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/256287/282094 refusal reason.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256271/why-i-can-favorite-a-question-but-not-an-answer/256287#comment835562_256287

Comment: Interestingly, the [often-cited canonical post on reconsideration requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89026/can-we-re-request-features-that-were-declined-a-sufficient-while-ago) uses this very request as its example.